# Reversal of a binary number using bit hacks

Tags: c++, bit

**Can someone please explain how the binary number is being reversed.**

```
unsigned rev = 0;
unsigned k = n;

while (k)
{
// add rightmost bit to rev 
    rev = (rev << 1) | (k & 1);
    k = k >> 1;     // drop last bit
            cout<<"k val is "<<bitset<8>(k)<<endl;
    cout<<"rev val is "<<{bitset<8>(rev)<<endl;
}
```

Output if n=9

k val is 00000100
rev val is 00000001
k val is 00000010
rev val is 00000010
k val is 00000001
rev val is 00000100
k val is 00000000
rev val is 00001001
9 is Palindrome

---

I was referring question 2 from here: http://www.techiedelight.com/bit-hacks-part-6-random-problems/

As far as I know, only first expression is executed if it is true for  "|" condition statement. So, here rev<<1 will be false only for first execution of loop but not for rest. Therefore how does rev get 1 in the end for last condition because (k&1) won't be executed. Only left shift will be executed right?

Comment: `|` is a bitwise OR, it's not the same as `||` (logical OR)

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/38-bitwise-operators/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One visualisation that may be useful is a stack: imagine your number `n` is represented by a stack of binary digits, the least significant digit being at the top of the stack.

A common algorithm for bit reversing is then to iteratively pop the digits one by one from the `n` stack and stack them in an other stack (representing `rev` in your case).

- `k = k >> 1;` pops one binary digit from the stack `n` (renamed as `k` in your code)
- `rev = (rev << 1) | (k & 1);` stacks the binary digit on the top of the `k` stack.

In the code, the pop/stack operations are reversed to avoid temporaries.

Finally, this operation of pop/stack should be repeated as long as there are digits in the `n` stack. This is because the `while` condition is only `k`, it tests whether or not `k` is 0 (no digits left).

---

PS: you have some low-level algorithms to perform bit-reversing on the [Bit Twiddling Hacks website](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious). The algorithms aim at performance and so may not be easily understandable.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know, only first expression is executed if it is true for "|" condition statement.

The | operator is a bit-wise OR: it’s value is the OR operation on the bit patterns of its two operands. It always evaluated both operands because it needs their full values.  Example:  3 | 5 is 7.

The || is a logical OR: it’s true if either operands (as an entire value) is true. It does not evaluate the 2nd operands if the first was true.

The code is using the | bit-wise OR to build up the answer one bit at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `rev` is initialized with `0`, it will contain the result. The `while` loop iterates while `k`, which is the input, has any set bits left. The first statement of the loop's body masks out the last bit of `k` and copies it it `rev`, which is shifted one bit to the left in the process (by the shift operator). In the loop iteration, both the input and the output are shifted - the inpu is shifted to the right, the output to the left.